# svn repository path changed: how to re-bind my local folder to it?

Tags: svn

i have an repository that is visible as e:/svn/repository and it is checked out to a local folder c:/work
Now repository path is changed to f:/general/svn/repository
what svn command to use in order for c:/work to be bound to the new repository path? i do not want to delete c:/work and doing fresh check out since c:/work contains lots on unversioned temp files that i want to keep in place

i have tried checkout f:/general/svn/repository into c:/work, svn gives error:
c:/work is already a working copy for a different url

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
cd c:\work
svn switch --relocate file:///E:/svn/repository file:///F:/general/svn/repository
```

Comment: done, seems to work
now i'm trying to commit my file ( c:\work contains newer ) and it fails with 'base checksum mismatch'. any hints?

Comment: iirc subversion does that if someone else modified the file since you last updated.  You need to do an svn update to merge the changes first.

Answer (score 2):

You want the [`svn switch`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html)`--relocate` command.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using TortoiseSVN in which case you'd choose "Relocate" and put in the new address.

Comment: done, seems to work
now i'm trying to commit my file ( c:\work contains newer ) and it fails with 'base checksum mismatch'. any hints?